# NSView overlaying NSPageController disappearing on transition

Tags: cocoa, drawing, nsview, nsviewcontroller

I have an NSPageController containing 8 or so NSViewControllers. I want to have a semi transparent bottom bar when the mouse is inside of the window, and a semi transparent top bar that persists no matter where the mouse is.

I add the top bar and bottom bar to the view, along with constraints in NSPageControllers viewDidLoad() method.

They show up fine on the first page, but when I start to transition from one page to another, the new NSViewController is redrawn over the overlaying views and they disappear. I can verify that they are under the NSViewControllers because then I drag all the way to a specific side I can see them underneath.

Any ideas why this is happening / how I can avoid it?

Code:

```
class MyPageController: NSPageController {

    // MARK: - Properties
    fileprivate var mouseIsInside = false

    fileprivate var tabBar: TabBar!

    // MARK: - NSViewController
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add tab bar, then hide it (mouse in or outside of window will restore current state)
        tabBar = TabBar(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y:0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 40))
        addTabBar(withAnimation: false)
        removeTabBar(withAnimation: false)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tabBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            tabBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tabBar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            tabBar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor)
        ])

        delegate = self
        transitionStyle = .horizontalStrip
        arrangedObjects = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]
        selectedIndex = 0
        view.wantsLayer = true

        // register for mouse events
        let trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: view.bounds, options: [.mouseEnteredAndExited, .mouseMoved, .activeAlways, .inVisibleRect], owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        view.addTrackingArea(trackingArea)          
    }       
}

// NSPageController Delegate
extension PageController: NSPageControllerDelegate {

    func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, frameFor object: Any?) -> NSRect {
        return NSInsetRect(view.frame, -1, 0)
    }

    func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, identifierFor object: Any) -> String {      
        return (object as? String)!
    }

    func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, viewControllerForIdentifier identifier: String) -> NSViewController {           
        return ViewController(id: identifier)
    }

    func pageControllerWillStartLiveTransition(_ pageController: NSPageController) {
        Swift.print("pageControllerWillStartLiveTransition")
        addTabBar(withAnimation: false)
    }

    func pageControllerDidEndLiveTransition(_ pageController: NSPageController) {
        pageController.completeTransition()
        addTabBar(withAnimation: false)
        Swift.print("pageControllerWillEndLiveTransition")
    }
}    

// tabBar functions
extension PageController {
    func addTabBar(withAnimation shouldAnimate: Bool) {
        view.addSubview(tabBar)
        tabBar.frame.size.width = view.frame.size.width

        if mouseIsInside {              
            tabBar.showWithAnimation(shouldAnimate)             
        }
    }

    func removeTabBar(withAnimation shouldAnimate: Bool) {          
        tabBar.hideWithAnimation(shouldAnimate)         
    }    
}

// Mouse Movements
extension PageController {

    override func mouseEntered(with event: NSEvent) {
        mouseIsInside = true
        addTabBar(withAnimation: true)
    }

    override func mouseExited(with event: NSEvent) {
        mouseIsInside = false
        removeTabBar(withAnimation: true)
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us your code please....http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This appear to be a not resolved bug. This fixed for me:

1. If the `pageController` is fullfilling the window's view, set to nil the `contentView`'s background. This way the background we'll see is always the background of the `pageController`.
2. Sort views in this method:

   ```
   func pageControllerDidEndLiveTransition(_ pageController: NSPageController) {
       let controller = selectedViewController as! (YOUR_NSVIEWCONTROLLER_CLASS)
       controller.view.superview?.addSubview(controller.view, positioned: .below, relativeTo: TOOLBAR)
   }
   ```

Replace `YOUR_NSVIEWCONTROLLER_CLASS` for your `ViewController`class name, and then replace `TOOLBAR` for the view that you want to see on top.